# Animation speed in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know how to display an animation in a c# script and show each of them, for example, every 5 frames but I don't know how I can display them like this: frame 1 -> 0.1 sec | frame 2 -> 0.54 sec | etc.
Does anyone know how to do this? or knowing any written scripts for this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? An actual `AnimationClip` with certain key frames or do you simply have some keyframe data and want to "animate" through these?

Comment: I mean, I have 3 sprites and I gave them to my script. I want the script to show them continuasly and each with their time when I press space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class Frame
{
    public Sprite sprite;
    public float duration;
}

public class FramePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I just assumed for now you are using an UI.Image component
    [SerializeField] private Image _image;

    // here you reference your sprites and adjust them accordingly
    // via the Inspector in Unity
    public Frame[] frames;

    // holds the index of the currently displayed frame
    private int _current;

    // timer for when to switch to the next frame
    private float _timer;

    

    private void Start()
    {
        // Get the Image component if not already referenced via Inspector
        if(!_image) _image = GetComponent<Image>();

        // setup the first frame 
        UpdateCurrentFrame();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // reduce by time passed since last frame
        _timer -= Time.deltaTime;

        // reached 0 ?
        if(_timer <= 0)
        {
            // increase by one but wrap arround at end of array
            _current = (_current + 1) % frames.Length;

            // go to the new frame
            UpdateCurrentFrame();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCurrentFrame()
    {
        // get current frame instance
        var currentFrame = frames[_current];

        // display the frame
        _image.sprite = currentFrame.sprite;

        // set timer for this frame
        _timer = currentFrame.duration;
    }
}
```